# How do your rearrange the photo album icons in Photos for iPad?

Tags: ipad, photos.app

How do you rearrange the photo album icons in Photos for iPad? I don't want to rearrange the pictures in the albums, just the icons of the various photo albums.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no way to move the "Camera Roll" album and the "My Photostream" album. These two albums are always at the top and in that order.

To arrange any other albums, including the automatically created "Videos", and "Panoramas" just tap "Edit" in the upper right corner. You can now tap (hold) and drag these albums around as you desire. They drag and drop in the same way that your home-screen icons do. When you have adjusted them as you like, you can tap the done button.

Answer (score 0):

I have wanted to re-organize my uploaded (from Picasa3 on my HP pc) photo albums in the "Web Albums" icon of my IPad.  I read the answer above and looked at my IPad and didn't see an "Edit" button on the main albums page.  But, I poked around and discovered how to do this.  If you click on your name at the top left of the screen it opens a menu of items including "Settings."  Click on "Settings" then click on "Viewing" and then click on "Album Sort."  This provides you with several ways of arranging your albums.  I clicked on "A to Z" and it instantly re-arranged my albums alphabetically, beginning with in ascending order those whose labels begin with years.  Finally, I can find my albums quickly without scrolling down looking through all of them.